# What's the VB.NET equivalent to Excel's Get & Transform function for Web sources?

Tags: excel, vb.net, powerquery

I'm trying to duplicate Excel's Get & Transform functionality in a VB.NET script. I want to load each URL from a list, and do the equivalent of loading all tables, as you would when using Data->From Web.

To illustrate what I'm talking about, here are a few screenshots:
Create a new `From Web` query.
[image: Create new From Web query]

Then select all the tables found and Load.
[image]

I would like to end up with something like this collection in `Queries & Connections`:
[image]

The closest I've come is by creating a new QueryTable using the URL, and saving all tables.

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim URL As String = Dts.Variables("User::URL").Value.ToString()
    Dim FileName As String = Dts.Variables("User::FileName").Value.ToString()
    Dim xlNone As XlWebFormatting = XlWebFormatting.xlWebFormattingNone
    Dim Format As XlFileFormat = XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows
    Dim ScrapeStatus As Integer = 1

    Dim excel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass

    With excel
        .SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add()

    With wb
        .Activate()
        .Worksheets.Select(1)
    End With

    Try

        Dim rnStart As Range = wb.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z100")
        Dim qtQtrResults As QueryTable = wb.ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" + URL, Destination:=rnStart)

        With qtQtrResults
            .BackgroundQuery = False
            .WebFormatting = xlNone
            .WebSelectionType = XlWebSelectionType.xlAllTables
            .Refresh()
        End With

        excel.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
        wb.SaveAs(FileName)

        wb.Close()
        excel.Quit()
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel)
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

    Catch ex As Exception

        Dts.Variables("User::Error").Value = ex.Message.ToString()
        wb.Saved = True
        wb.Close()
        excel.Quit()
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel)
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure

    End Try

End Sub
```

This puts all the tables into a single sheet, and the .xlsx file ends up containing one Connection under `Queries & Connections` instead of N tables under the Queries tab. 
[image]

So, is there a VB.NET equivalent to Excel's Data->From Web UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive searching of various VB* documentation, I found that the functionality I'm looking for comes from the Power Query tool. Currently it only exists in VBA, starting with Excel 2016.

The collection `Workbook.Queries` contains `WorkbookQuery` objects that represent Power Query queries.